# Get different frames from one file ( H264 codec)

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, h.264

I try to transmit video to another client(video call), using library ffmpeg and encoder - libx264, decoder - h264. For this i have one "core" library, which used in two clients.

On sender:

- 1. encode **AVFrame** and get **AVPacket**;
- 2. transform **AVPacket**.*data* to byte array and length for
     transmiting (for debugging i save this byte array to file).

On reciver:

- 1. save recived byte array to file;
- 2. get **AVPacket** from this byte array;
- 3. decode **AVPacket** to **AVFrame**.

Result of this:
array files(saved byte_array), which equals on sender and reciver but some frames are different (some part of frame on reciver is corrupted).
Like this:[image: Corrupted frame]

What possible reason of this?

Comment: How do you transmit your stream? RTP, UDP, TCP or something else?

Comment: @MarkusSchumann rtp protocol